# WinHttpHandler is now internal? Has something replaced it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

WinHttpHandler is an internal class therefore trying to use it brings up a inaccessibility error.   I need to set SslProtocols to enable the application for the most recent version of TLS.  Is there a replacement for this class or do I need to go back to an earlier version of it?

I tried an earlier version of the class which works but that's not the best practice.

```
 WinHttpHandler httpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
 httpHandler.SslProtocols = 
   SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls;
```

I expect to be able to use this class within using System.Net.Http

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Sets the default protocols globally for the process.  Works on .NET 4.5+.  On .NET 4.0 the newer protocols are not defined.